# Linked list is not displaying

Tags: c

I'm new to C, just started learning Linked List.I think my add functions works correctly, but it doesn't seem to display my linked list. I am getting no errors or warnings, and it doesn't crash.

`struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};
typedef struct node *User;

User newUser()
{
    User newNode;
    newNode = (User)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newNode->next = NULL;

    return newNode;
}
void add(User head, int x)
{
    User temp, p;

    temp = newUser();
    temp->data = x
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        head = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        p = head;
        while(p != NULL)
        {
            p = p->next;
        }
        p->next = head;
    }
}
void displayData(User head)
{
    User temp;

    temp = head;

    while(head != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ",temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}`

EDIT: How I call the function

User head= NULL

add(head,10);

displayData(head);

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a [debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Where and how are you calling `displayData`? Please include the `main` function, and whatever else relevant code that is missing. Also, in the `while(head != NULL)` loop, shouldn't `head` be modified at some point?

Comment: BTW: `typedef struct node *User;`: hiding pointer types behind typedefs is a really bad idea, it only adds confusion, even more for beginners.

Comment: You need to [edit]  your question and add a [mcve]. We cannot guess _how_ you call your functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't show how you call `add` but even so, it is very easy to see why it isn't working.

When you use a variable in a function call, like for example

```
User mylist;

add(mylist, 10);
```

the value of `mylist` remains unchanged because you are only passing the value of it to `add`.

Some languages have the ability to pass by reference, but C doesn't. But instead you can pass a pointer to a variable.

```
add(&mylist, 10);
```

and then `add` becomes something like...

```
void add(User *head, int x)
{
    User temp, p;

    temp = newUser();
    temp->data = x
    if(*head == NULL)
    {
        *head = temp;
    // etc...
```

and where you used `head` before, you de-reference it so that you're using the value of `mylist` and if you change the value of `*head` you're changing the value of `mylist`.

Also your `typedef` of `User` makes for very hard to read code as it hides the fact that it is actually a pointer to `struct node` - you should make it just be a `typedef` of `struct node` and then it is easier to see when you have a pointer or not.

Comment: That's a start, but there is still a problem in the `else` part of `add`: at the end of the `while` loop `p` is `NULL` and `p->next` will therefore unconditionally dereference a NULL pointer...

Comment: ...And there is also a blatant bug in `displayData`